# ModuleNotFoundError, why I am getting this?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the follow repository structure:

```
main_repo/
├── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── mod0
│   ├── code_0.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│ 
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_m1.py
├── module1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── m1.py
│   ├── m2.py
│   ├── m3.py
```

I have a little setup.py file with the following code

```
import os
import sys

if sys.argv[-1] == 'run1':
    os.system('python3 test/test_m1.py')
    sys.exit()
```

As you can see, I just want to execute `python3 setup.py run1` to execute my `test_m1.py` file. But I have a `ModuleNotFoundError`, and I don't know why since I have a `__init__.py` file in every repo.

Additionnally, the import I used on the file I want to test is in the form of `from module1.m1 import *`. The output error is `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named module1`.

Do I need to add something else to get the import done correctly?

Comment: I think your import statement is the problem (`from module1.m1 import *)`. Is this under `sys.path`? I believe python would interpret module1 as a package and be searching there for module m1. Change that to `from module1 import m1`. Or `import module1`.

Comment: I tried those two but i have the same error, no module named module1, and for `sys.path`, the first element its a path from `home/` to `main_repo`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I feel like it has to be a pathing problem though. You could try putting the package in the same exact folder as the test script. If this works, then it's a pathing problem. If that doesn't work, then try importing just the individual module from the same folder. If that then works, it is a problem with the package. If that doesn't work, python is broken lol.